# TSP nearest neighbor algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, nearest-neighbor, traveling-salesman

I seem to have stumped myself. I have written a TSP "solver" using the brute force method, but now I want to try the nearest neighbour algorithm. Here is the [BruteForce](http://pastebin.com/cCM2SYHB) class along with the [City](http://pastebin.com/59YRdtr2) class, the [Route](http://pastebin.com/cuGFygqP) class and the [Driver](http://pastebin.com/NYyYtqyK). I started writing the [Route](http://pastebin.com/KGii2TML) class for my nearest neighbour algorithm however I have no idea how to implement the nearest neighbour algorithm. I have searched for examples online, but I didn't find anything helpful. Is there anything that I can look at in order to implement this?